# Problems upgrading MVC Mini Profiler to latest release

Tags: c#, .net, mvc-mini-profiler

I've been using Mini Profiler in dev and production (azure) for a while and LOVE it.

It tried to upgrade to the latest release today via NUGET.  The DLL get's placed in the bin but my site gets an error.  If I go back to the old dll it works fine.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'MvcMiniProfiler, Version=2.0.4177.17902, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MvcMiniProfiler, Version=2.0.4177.17902, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MvcMiniProfiler, Version=2.0.4177.17902, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MvcMiniProfiler, Version=2.0.4177.17902, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   MyGlobal.application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Nate\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrainerRoad\com.TrainerRoad.DataAccess\MyGlobal.cs:15
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to read the documentation on http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

In particular:

- Ensure you remove all the modifications you made to web.config.
- If you are profiling Entity Framework grab the MiniProfiler.EF package
- If you are running latest EF see: [Problem using SQL Server CE with Entity Framework code-first and ASP.NET MVC 3 and mvc miniprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560624/problem-using-sql-server-ce-with-entity-framework-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3-an/7576705#7576705)

There is not MiniProfiler version `2.0.4177.17902` so I really do not know where it is coming from.

Comment: I had another library with a reference to 1.2.  I just rebuilt that with 1.9 and it worked.